# angularjs and google cloud service end point page redirect

Tags: angularjs, oauth-2.0

my sign in page js looks like below
app.controller('UserController', function(){
        this.user = userStatus;

```
    userAuthed = function() {
        var request = gapi.client.oauth2.userinfo.get().execute(function(resp) {
            if (!resp.code) {
                if(userStatus.isSignedIn){
                    userStatus.isSignedIn = false;
                }else{
                     userStatus.isSignedIn = true;
                }
            }else{
                userStatus.isSignedIn = false;
            }
          });
        };

    this.doLogin = function(){      
         gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: CLIENT_ID,
              scope: SCOPES, immediate: false},
              userAuthed);
    };

});
```

it works as expected. However, how do i know go to a new page from here after successful authentication with google oauth?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs#gapiauthauthorizeparams--------callback), there's a callback you can handle. The callback gives you an [auth token](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs#oauth-20-token-object) you can use to see how the request went.

Comment: i have two different projects one that has google cloud end point implementation and another  project that has the web interface. First thing that I am confused is that should i use oath client key for the web project or for the services project to login?